# d3 drag node behaviour doesn't work

Tags: d3.js, jsfiddle, force-layout

I am new to d3 and have been trying various examples all of last night.

I have managed to put together this code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kawshik84/ao3e0adq/):

```
var width = 960,
        height = 500;
d3.select(window)
        .on("keydown", keydown);

var selectedNode = null;

var force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([width, height])
        .charge(-400)
        .linkDistance(40)
        .on("tick", tick);

var drag = force.drag()
        .on("dragstart", dragstart);
var outer = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("pointer-events", "all");

var svg = outer.append("svg:g")
        .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", rescale))
        .on("dblclick.zoom", null);


var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
        node = svg.selectAll(".node");

// rescale g
function rescale() {
    var trans=d3.event.translate;
    var scale=d3.event.scale;

    svg.attr("transform",
            "translate(" + trans + ")"
            + " scale(" + scale + ")");
}


d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
    force
            .nodes(graph.nodes)
            .links(graph.links)
            .start();

    link = link.data(graph.links)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link");

    node = node.data(graph.nodes);

    node.enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", 12)
            .on("dblclick", function(d){
                d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = false);
            })
            .on("click", function(d){
                node.classed("selected",false);
                d3.select(this).classed("selected", true);

            })
            .call(drag);
});

function tick() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}


function dragstart(d) {
    d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
}

function mousemove() {
//        if (!mousedown_node) return;
//
//        // update drag line
//        drag_line
//                .attr("x1", mousedown_node.x)
//                .attr("y1", mousedown_node.y)
//                 .attr("x2", d3.svg.mouse(this)[0])
//                .attr("y2", d3.svg.mouse(this)[1]);

}

function mousedown(){
//        svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom"), rescale());
}

function mouseup() {}


function keydown() {

    if (d3.event.keyCode == 65) {
        if (!selectedNode) {
            alert ("no node selected");
            return;
        } else {

        }



    }


}
```

I am not sure why this jsfiddle isn't working as it works in my browser. Can someone please have a look. So where I am stuck is trying to add a drag behaviour to the nodes.  I would like to add the option of dragging the nodes around instead of simply relying on the force layout. So for example, when a node is selected and a certain key on the keyboard is pressed i would like to move the node instead of draw. Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the fiddle is not working because of the missing "*graph.json*" file. I just updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ao3e0adq/2/)

```
d3.json("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/uki0gmdvp7vrtm9/graph.json", function(error, graph) {
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the jsfiddle problem. Now if anyone can help with the dragging option please.

Comment: I am sorry, my mistake. I think the dragging problem was already resolved when I posted the problem. The problem I am having is that I would like to add a new node to the graph when I click on an empty space. And ofcourse keep the dragging functionality as it is.

Comment: May be you should ask a new question. Also, please consider accepting my answer.